# How to persists a session value through out all the pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am storing USER_ID to the session after LOGIN.
It's not working for me. I am working with multiple pages. So, once I update the session at one page it should maintain the same value through all the pages. but it's loading the other pages with a blank session value.

Here what I feel is I am using a common js file(AppCtrl.js) for all the pages(LoginController, HomepageController, and so on). so, it might happen that every time it initiates a new session as by being included in every page.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: The plnkr(I have implemented): http://plnkr.co/edit/Fg3uF4ukl5p88Z0AeQqU?p=preview

Comment: But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) to store user info through client pages

Comment: Then how can I access the stored value at the next html page ?

Comment: please read the document, simply set `localStorageService.set('userId','111-222-333');`
then get it in other controller `localStorageService.get('userId');`

Answer (score 0):

You could define a "global" service which is injected in each of your controllers and which stores your persistent variables.